# Listen requires 1 or 2 arguments

Tags: apache, wamp, wampserver

I'm new to wamp and im trying to run it for the first time. but when i look to the event viewer im getting the following error. "Listen requires 1 or 2 arguments". Im trying to change the port because IIS is already running in port 80

here is my Listen in httpd.conf 
Listen 111.222.111.111:818Listen [::0]:818

Comment: Why did you run two `Listen` directives together onto one line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are 2 seperate parameters and should be coded in httpd.conf.

Also you dont need the actual ip address so just use 0.0.0.0 as the ip adress for the IPV4 network.

Also you are better to use a port number greater that 1024 as the range 0 to 1024 is used by other standard software, so try a larger port number.

Like so:-

```
Listen 0.0.0.0:8000
Listen [::0]:8000
```

You will also have to change this line in httpd.conf to match the port number you have decided to use.

```
ServerName localhost:8000
```

Suggestion:

If you are not actually using IIS it would be easier to uninstall it, and stay with port 80 for Apache. All browsers assume port 80 and if you use another port you have to remember to use it on all urls. Also it is afterall a web server and if you are not using it, and have no idea how to secure it, it is just another potential attack vector on your PC